# How do I deal with a silent video per WCAG 2.0's Success Criterion 1.2.5?

Tags: video, wai-aria, wcag2.0

I'm not sure how to deal with WCAG 2.0's [success criterion 1.2.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#media-equiv-audio-desc-only). It says:

> Audio description is provided for all prerecorded video content in synchronized media

Do I have to provide an audio description for a **silent video**, showing how to build a paper plane to meet AA? The [definition of synchronized media](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/media-equiv-audio-desc-only.html#synchronizedmediadef) unfortunately doesn't appear to be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case 1.2.1 is relevant, not 1.2.5, because you have a video without sound. See "[video-only](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#video-onlydef)":

> a time-based presentation that contains only video (no audio and no interaction)

**[1.2.1 Audio-only and Video-only (Prerecorded)](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#media-equiv-av-only-alt)** says:

> For prerecorded audio-only and prerecorded video-only media, the following are true, except when the audio or video is a media alternative for text and is clearly labeled as such: (Level A)
>
> - […]
> - **Prerecorded Video-only:** Either an alternative for time-based media or an audio track is provided that presents equivalent information for prerecorded video-only content.

So you'd have to provide an alternative to the video, like a text explaining how to build a paper plane or a spoken record of that explanation.

/edit: Ah, sorry, I read over that you want to get AA. So yeah, as far as I understand you'd *have* to offer an audio track for the video-only.

---

I think it would be helpful to explicitly state that there is no audio at all, too. But this is not a requirement afair.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the hint concerning the note that there is no audio at all. I think the guidelines should offer a more precise definition of "synchronized media" after all.